How to do android lib from part of multimodule app
Create lib from android app screen
My current task is to separate one of the application screens as a library so that another application can have it and keep all the functionality of the screen
The screen consists of 3 modules of clean architecture: Ui, Domain & Data and it works fine in the application. Also, we have some utills modules in UI & Data layers.
Our modules have the com.android.library plugin
How can I create such feature as a library without changing the current architecture of the project (i.e. keep the current modules intact)
And I also think that there will be problems combining the DI code of the library and the client code. (We use Koin). But now it is not big problem.
Project look like
root
|-- app
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- src
        |-- CombineFeatures
|-- ui
    |-- feature1
        |-- build.gradle
        |-- src
            |-- Feature1UICode
|-- domain
    |-- feature1
        |-- build.gradle
        |-- src
            |-- Feature1DomainCode
|-- data
    |-- feature1
        |-- build.gradle
        |-- src
            |-- Feature1DataCode
|-- settings.gradle

Attempts
I tried to build the AAR library from the UI module using the gradle assemble task, however, it did not have the rest of the clean layers and denepndecies from project (like material3 etc.) , which is why I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of....
In this case, I could only invoke the functions of the imported module.
Can I combine several AAR files into one? As variant, I can try use fat-aar-lib -> Building aar library from multimodule project. But it seems like not modern solution.
We do not consider the option of moving the functionality to a separate project and repository, because it will be difficult to maintain in future
Also, earlier we tried to make composite builds, but it was very slow and forced us to have all the source code (of the project) locally, so we abandoned this option

Rather than a Composite Build, I think you need something slightly similar, but instead you should pursue a Multi-module Build.
In order to create a Multi-module project, you should aim to extract all the code pertaining to the application feature you're moving into it's own Gradle module, and make this into an Android library.  Therefore, go into File >> New >> New Module and then select the Android library module option.

From here, should should create a new hierarchy similar to the one you already described as to keep everything congruent, and then add an extra directory to set up all of the DI, as needed.
root
|-- app
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- src
        |-- UI
        |-- Domain
        |-- Data
|-- feature/newModule [the new feature module we're creating]
    |-- build.gradle
    |-- src
        |-- UI
        |-- Domain
        |-- Data
        |-- DI [specify all of the di needs for this module]
|-- settings.gradle

Make sure to specify your new module inside the settings.gradle file correctly:
// settings.gradle
...
include ':feature/newModule'

And to update the app's build.gradle to contain your submodule project for use:
/// build.gradle
...
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":feature/newModule"))
    ...
}

For more information on multi-module architecture, check out Android's official documentation.

I didn't quite understand this answer.
The question was more about how to assemble one feature (a screen with all layers) as a library (for example, AAR). All our modules are already android library.
Now I have a feature consisting of 3+ modules depending as follows
ui -> domain -> data -> utils
I need to build this feature as a library and use it in another application, interacting through callbacks.
That is, another application should invoke, for example
implementation(files("featureLib"))
FeatureScreen(callback1 = {}, callback2 = {})
